# How to display Image from Firebase storage in React-native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, async-await, react-native, firebase-storage

I am trying to display my image from Firebase storage in my React-native app. I get the download URL through this `async` function:

```js
async function getImage() {
  const url = await storage()
  .ref('garnele.jpg')
  .getDownloadURL()
  console.log(url)
  return url
}
```

My problem is how to pass the URL to the Image component. I tried:

```html
<Image
    source={{uri: getImage() }}
 />
```

but it only returns the object.

I also found `getImage().then(result => console.log(result))` - but I don't know how to use it in my case.

Comment: I don't have React experience, but related issues suggest storing the return value of the async function in the component's state: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59070347/image-source-in-async-function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929760/getting-an-image-uri-into-render-from-an-async-function

Comment: thanks a lot, that was the post i was Looking for!

Answer (score 9):

It is probably not the cleaner solution as I'm still learning react native and firebase products, but, here is what I did :

```
import storage from '@react-native-firebase/storage';
```

[@react-native-firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-firebase/storage) and [doc](https://rnfirebase.io/storage/usage)

```
const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(undefined);

useEffect(() => {
    storage()
      .ref('/' + 'FA984B65-38D4-44B1-BF02-4E7EF089773B.jpg') //name in storage in firebase console
      .getDownloadURL()
      .then((url) => {
        setImageUrl(url);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log('Errors while downloading => ', e));
  }, []);

return (
    <Image style={{height: 200, width: 200}} source={{uri: imageUrl}} />
);
```